# How do I delete the repeating word in vi editor?

Tags: vi

I want to delete certain word in multiple locations ( say I want to delete the word " involve" form Vi editor and it appear 10000 times) from a vi editor?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to delete all occurrences of "involve", that is done with a standard vi command, e.g.,

```
:%s/\<involve\>//g
```

On the other hand, if you want to delete exactly 10000 occurrences, you need something more involved, one of vim's extensions.

The markers `\<` and `\>` are used to ensure that you do not change words such as "involved", "involvement", etc.

Comment: Note: this may leave extra spaces or blank lines or lines containing just a `.` in some cases.

Comment: Agreed, but allowing for space before/after and allowing for beginning/ending of line, as well as adjacent punctuation would make the answer more complex than the question.